# What does "just as with" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "LIKE" here?
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just%20as

Of course, **just as with** most behaviors and personality traits we would like our children to develop, the most effective form of teaching is by example. The best way to raise conscientious and curious kids is to let them see us being conscientious and curious ourselves.

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/lawrencelight/2017/06/13/why-the-secret-to-getting-rich-isnt-being-smart/2/#3ea6b6a85c7a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just as with* is another way of saying:

> > in common with
> >
> > as is the case with
> >
> > as is typical with

It is a way of comparing common features in different things/circumstances.

Your Merriam Webster reference to *Just as* omits the preposition *with*. So while *Just as....* also leads to a comparison of one kind or another, the *with* leads directly into the things being compared.